# PHPMyAdmin Checking Out STABLE not working

Tags: git, github, phpmyadmin, sourceforge

I am trying to check out the most Stable release of PHPMyAdmin via Git. I have many Directions online but none of them see to work.

Here is the process and where I get hung up:

Step 1: `git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.git` Works!

Step 2: `cd phpmyadmin` Works!

Step 3: `git checkout -t origin/STABLE` Does Not Work :-(

I revive this error:

`fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'STABLE' at the same time.`
`Did you intend to checkout 'origin/STABLE' which can not be resolved as commit?`
Then I just end up at the prompt to try again.

I have also tried `master/STABLE` & `origin/master/STABLE`

Currently the directions all point to github, but I keep seeing SourceForge from PHPMyAdmin.net Am I pointing to the wrong place?

Any Help would be greatly Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is in the first line, where we think that the clone completed correctly for our needs.

When you make the `git clone` call with the `--depth` option, you're only grabbing the most recent commit *on the default branch of the remote* and no other history or branches. The remote has a default branch of `master`, which means that you're not downloading `STABLE` at all.

From the Git documentation for [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), emphasis mine:

> `--[no-]single-branch`
>
> Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the `--branch` option or the primary branch remote's `HEAD` points at. **When creating a shallow clone with the `--depth` option, this is the default, unless `--no-single-branch` is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches**. Further fetches into the resulting repository will only update the remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning. If the `HEAD` at the remote did not point at any branch when `--single-branch` clone was made, no remote-tracking branch is created.

There are a few different ways to fix this up, but the easiest is to clone it properly for what you're wanting, by using the `--branch` option to clone the tip of the branch that you actually want.

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch=STABLE git://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.git
```

It's smaller to download than running the clone with `--no-single-branch` because that gets all of the commits; for that repository it's `~60MB` for `--branch=STABLE` vs `~140MB` for `--no-single-branch`.

Comment: For anyone searching for this today, the URL is now on the HTTPS protocol making the URL "https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.git". You'll get connection refused if you use the GIT protocol.